# Low-level function call to other contract is causing revert with correct function selector

Tags: solidity, revert, function-selector, abi.encodewithsignature, address.call

I have 2 contracts, `FloorInfo` and `Elevator`.

I want to call the `goTo(uint)` in the `Elevator` contract from the `FloorInfo` contract using a low-level call, this happens in the `go()` function inside the `FloorInfo` contract. Executing `go()` causes a revert.

It only does not revert if I make an interface for the `Elevator` contract, attach it to `InstanceAddr` and reimplement `go()` as :

```
Elevator(InstanceAddr).goTo(1)
```

Why is this the case?

## FloorInfo.sol

```
contract FloorInfo {
    address private InstanceAddr = 0x804a8a48135EBdfb99e56811F157722A825AD823;
    int isLastFloorCallCount;

    //to be called by contract at *InstanceAddr*
    function isLastFloor(uint _floor) public returns (bool) {
        isLastFloorCallCount++;
        
        if(isLastFloorCallCount == 1)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    function go() external {
        (InstanceAddr).call{value:0}(
              abi.encodeWithSignature("goTo(uint)", 1)
        );
    }
}
```

## Elevator.sol

```
interface FloorInfoInterface {
  function isLastFloor(uint) external returns (bool);
}


contract Elevator {
  bool public top;
  uint public floor;

  function goTo(uint _floor) public {
    FloorInfoInterface floorInfo = FloorInfoInterface(msg.sender);

    if (! floorInfo.isLastFloor(_floor)) {
      floor = _floor;
      top = floorInfo.isLastFloor(floor);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't have to set the value to 0 when you call the **go()** function .
2. call low level function returns two values , a boolean and bytes . Try to
   store these two values in variables .

```js
function go() external {
           (bool success , bytes memory data) = InstanceAddr.call(
                 abi.encodeWithSignature("goTo(uint)", 1)
           );
            require(success , "call failed");

       }
```

3. Make sure the instance address is correct .